# Keyboard not working after suspend to ram (sleep)

Tags: keyboard, suspend

On a Sony Vaio VGN CS21S the keyboard doesn´t work after suspend to ram. Suspend to disk (hibernate) works though. Running a fresh install of Natty with Unity.

Comment: I've tried using adding "atkbd.reset to /etc/default/grub after the "quiet splash". This fixes the keyboard problem but now the touchpad is not responding any more.

Comment: After 11 years, I'm still having the issue and can't find a workaround...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual solution to this problem is:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
```

Then, run `update-grub` and reboot.

Credit: jmkhenka @ http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1335007.html

Works for me on Lenovo Thinkpad X230.

Comment: Same here linux 5.9.3, Sony Vaio SVE 1512, suspend to ram &rarr; keyboard defunct; suspend to disk afterwards makes it functioning again.  
Loading the module `atkbd` with the option `reset=1` (in case if it is statically compiled into the kernel, adding `atkbd.reset=1` to the boot command line) did solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Same notebook and same problems here.

I'll suggest you to take a look at this! 
http://techiesurgeon.blogspot.com/2011/05/get-beautiful-ubuntu-natty-running-on.html

In addition to your fix it suggests to add psmouse to /etc/modules so to address touchpad issue.

It worked fine for me.

Cheers,
Fabbree

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...