# Ubuntu 17.04 keyboard not responding after suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 17.04

I have a Sony Vaio SVF142C1WW with 64-bit Ubuntu 17.04 installed. Every time it resumes from being suspended, neither the keyboard nor touchpad work for a few seconds. Then the touchpad becomes responsive but the keyboard still remains non-responsive.

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 where both the keyboard and touchpad did become responsive after a few seconds of non-responsiveness. I've tried answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38797/keyboard-not-working-after-suspend-to-ram-sleep?rq=1) but nothing worked. What else can I try?

Comment: Switched to kernel version 4.8 and the keyboard works fine now. Will I run into any troubles because of this change?

Answer (score 13):

@Saif has found the underlying driver which is behind the issue. However setting dumbkbd and direct is unnecessary / disables system control of LEDs like Caps-Lock.

For most vaios instead resetting the controller will also correct the problem whilst maintaining this functionality. I.e. in the grub config file -

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset"
```

Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Can confirmed this with a laptop - model N150RF1 (Brand varies). Have never been able to use the keyboard after a shutdown before this

Comment: NOTE : This does not work on Sony Vaio SVF series. Only i8042.dumbkbd works, and there is no way around the led bug.

Answer (score 12):

Basically, run this in a shell to confirm you are applicable to this solution:

```
dmesg | grep i8042
```

and confirm you get this output

```
[ 1.514469] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBC,PNP0f13:MOUE] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[ 1.525273] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[ 1.525287] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[ 1.526035] input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[ 21.927438] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input10
```

then, add the boot parameters `i8042.direct` and `i8042.dumbkbd` to `/etc/default/grub`. For example, run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that begins `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and edit it to include the new parameters, so that after your edit it looks something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"
```

Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Source: Some time traveler [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224316)

Comment: That's an old post. Why do you think it will work here?

Comment: Because I was facing the issue yesterday, with latest kernel and latest distro release. And it was hard to find a solution specific for Vaio laptopts. This might be handy for other victims like me, since this solved the issue.

Comment: so it worked for you? that's great if so! :)

Comment: Worked for my (slightly aged) Sony Vaio running 64-bit Ubuntu 17.04. Great!

Comment: It worked but CapsLock, NumLock lights always on. So something is wrong here!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.10 with Sony Vaio SVF series laptop, there is no way around led light no bug, touchpad touch click not working bug , so restart is needed to restore fully working system.

Comment: I have HP elitebook and it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Worked on an old Sony Vaio with a touchscreen and Ubuntu 20. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

My ThinkPad E531 mouse and suspend functions works again after:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="atkbd.reset=1 i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset=1 i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1 quiet splash"
```

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 1):

For the VAIO model vjf152 sold in Japan only, the solution is to replace content in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` with `atkdb.reset i8042.nomux quiet splash` and then do `sudo update-grub`.

Found this on a Japanese forum: https://obelisk.hatenablog.com/category/Linux?page=1483896200

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my PC with Ubuntu 16.04. After returning from Suspend mode the password input box was not responding to keyboard events (was not even blinking). Reconnecting USB keyboard did not help. I could switch with Ctrl+F2 to terminal. The keyboard worked - just the input box did not.

Open grub default config file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
```

run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then reboot ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't get any proper permanent solutions to this problem, I could find a workaround.

What I did was,  turn on On-Screen Keyboard, Press CapsLock on the On-Screen Keyboard,  and turn it back off.

And Voila, the keyboard started working Again!!!

But as I said, it's not permanent, you have to do this Everytime.

Answer (score 0):

There is one weird thing that worked for me.
My laptop is HP Elitebook 8460p.
When I have such a problem, I press Power button on the laptop to make it sleep again. Then I press Power button again to wake it up. And the keyboard works..
I have no idea why it is so...

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem on my Hp pro book running ubuntu 21.10. Everytime I suspend the computer and resume it the keyboard doesn’t work, i simple just press the power button to go back into suspend and resume it again and voila the keyboard works again.
Hope this helps.