# Keyboard not responding after waking up from suspend [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 18.04

My laptop is Sony Vaio SVE15114FXS. It used to work fine, no problem with networking and keyboard and mouse back to the days of 14.04

But now, with fresh installed 18.04, after waking up from suspend, wired-network is down and the keyboard is not responding. Only the touch pad is still working!

I solve the problem with networking by `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`. The keyboard remain unresolvable.

`dmesg | grep i8042` gave this

```
[    0.974841] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.977550] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.977554] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.996742] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    1.948806] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
```

So I tried all the solutions in which modifying the GRUB such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend) and also reinstalled `xserver-xorg-input-all`. But no solution work!

what could possibly go wrong with my i8042 controller?

Answer (score -1):

Saw the following in another forum:

Issue fixed by uninstalling Xscreensaver

```
$ sudo apt remove x-screensaver
```

Comment: there is no package named `x-sreensaver` nor `xscreensaver` is installed. Thank you.