# Laptop, keyboard and mousepad don't work on Lenovo V15 G4 AMN - Type 82YU

Tags: keyboard, mouse, lenovo

I have bought a Laptop and installed Ubuntu, but my keyboard and trackpad don't work.

If I plug in an external keyboard or mouse, it does work.
My laptop model is Lenovo V15 G4 AMN - Type 82YU.

I am running ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64 and I followed [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend) for some advice, but I fear that this is only for Intel CPUs, and mine is an AMD.

Comment: It is unlikely that this occurs due to the CPU being Intel or AMD. As mentioned in the "answer" below, please install hwinfo with `sudo apt install hwinfo` and then edit your question with the output of `sudo hwinfo --short`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model Lenovo V15 G4 AMN - Type 82YU and I am suffering from the same issue. Can you share the keyboard device?

You may use the following command to install hwinfo:

sudo apt install hwinfo

and then list the devices using:

sudo hwinfo --short

You may find more information here by the way:

https://linux-hardware.org/?computer=5af3a4db8b97

They seem to have detected the following keyboards:

1.Medion AG MD 86996

2.AT Translated Set 2 keyboard

But neither of them have been tested on LENOVO V15 G4 AMN - TYPE 82YU laptop i.e. the laptop that we are using.