# Can't type encryption password in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, encryption

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed with *LVM encryption option*. I know the password to unlock but I can't type it while booting the OS after Ubuntu and/or GRUB update. All keyboard keys have strange behavior. F.I. *Enter*, *Shift*, *Backspace* keys don't work as expected each adding some symbols into a command line. Meanwhile *Numeric* keys (1-0) don't add one symbol but more and change UI background, and *H/h-key* works exactly as *Enter* button and confirms the entered passphrase. But all the buttons work well if I boot BIOS/UEFI or LIVE CD/USB or even in GRUB *before* entering the unlock section.

**What I have done to let this happen**

I realized my keyboard stops reacting after my laptop goes in a suspend mode. I found this topic [Ubuntu 17.04 keyboard not responding after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend) and performed actions in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/940323 making sure I have the similar *i8042* log:

```
dmesg | grep i8042
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"
sudo update-grub
```

After that I had to force shutdown the laptop because it had freezed while making some stuff. Then I got the mentioned problem.

**What I have done to solve this**

The first obvious thought was this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` broke something. So I tried to fix it reconfiguring the GRUB.

1. I found an article [How to reinstall grub from a liveUSB if the / partition is encrypted and there is a separate /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i),
2. Booted using my live USB,
3. Mounted my encrypted volume:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda? TAG
mount /dev/[VOLUME GROUP NAME]/[LOGICAL VOLUME NAME] /mnt
```

4. Changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` back:

```
chroot /mnt
nano /etc/default/grub
```

5. Performed all the other commands to reinstall GRUB.

That didn't change anything but I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/719475/723783 step by step about 3 times.

I had a thought it didn't update EFI so:

1. I deleted all boot options in BIOS/UEFI and formatted my EFI partion,
2. Repeated all steps in https://askubuntu.com/a/719475/723783,
3. Rebooted and didn't get any boot option in GRUB nor GRUB boot menu itself.

After that I found a *Boot-Repair* tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair:

1. I formatted my EFI partion and deleted all boot option in BIOS/UEFI,
2. Installed *Boot-Repair*,
3. Ran *Boot-Repair* and got a message the tool sees my encrypted partition and I should unlock it first,
4. Unlocked my partition using

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda? TAG
```

5. Ran *Boot-Repair* and completed all commands it gave me,
6. Rebooted and got GRUB menu with ubuntu option,
7. Got the same keyboard typing issue again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like changes made in `/etc/default/grub` in live USB mode were not applied. I managed to boot recovery mode and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` had old unchanged value `"quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"`. Changed it back and ran `update-grub`.