# My keyboard does not work after Ubuntu 17.10 resumes from suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 17.10

I have an issue with my Sony Vaio SVE15128CXS laptop.
Only when I choose to suspend it in the top right hand corner, or close the laptop to make it suspend, my keyboard stops working after resume.

I can only use the screen keyboard to login and after that, I have to save my work and restart the computer to use it normally.

It does not happen if I leave the computer on and it goes to sleep mode by itself.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Device: Sony Vaio E series

Solution to the problem which worked for me:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` using the command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
```

Save the file and exit, then to make the change effective, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Solution found here:
[Keyboard not working after suspend to ram (sleep)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38797/keyboard-not-working-after-suspend-to-ram-sleep)